# Signal Sigabrt Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, sigabrt

I cloned this project from Github and when I build and ran it it showed up this Sigabrt error. The console says,

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
MoltinSwiftExample(10351,0x700000323000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff288d71cc0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Here is my code.

```
#import "SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.h"
#import "SDWebImageDecoder.h"
#import "UIImage+MultiFormat.h"
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>
#import "SDWebImageManager.h"

NSString *const SDWebImageDownloadStartNotification = @"SDWebImageDownloadStartNotification";
NSString *const SDWebImageDownloadReceiveResponseNotification = @"SDWebImageDownloadReceiveResponseNotification";
NSString *const SDWebImageDownloadStopNotification = @"SDWebImageDownloadStopNotification";
NSString *const SDWebImageDownloadFinishNotification = @"SDWebImageDownloadFinishNotification";

@interface SDWebImageDownloaderOperation () <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

@property (copy, nonatomic) SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock progressBlock;
@property (copy, nonatomic) SDWebImageDownloaderCompletedBlock completedBlock;
@property (copy, nonatomic) SDWebImageNoParamsBlock cancelBlock;

@property (assign, nonatomic, getter = isExecuting) BOOL executing;
@property (assign, nonatomic, getter = isFinished) BOOL finished;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData *imageData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *connection;
@property (strong, atomic) NSThread *thread;

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_4_0
@property (assign, nonatomic) UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTaskId;
#endif

@end

@implementation SDWebImageDownloaderOperation {
    size_t width, height;
    UIImageOrientation orientation;
    BOOL responseFromCached;
}

@synthesize executing = _executing;
@synthesize finished = _finished;

- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
              options:(SDWebImageDownloaderOptions)options
             progress:(SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock)progressBlock
            completed:(SDWebImageDownloaderCompletedBlock)completedBlock
            cancelled:(SDWebImageNoParamsBlock)cancelBlock {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _request = request;
        _shouldDecompressImages = YES;
        _shouldUseCredentialStorage = YES;
        _options = options;
        _progressBlock = [progressBlock copy];
        _completedBlock = [completedBlock copy];
        _cancelBlock = [cancelBlock copy];
        _executing = NO;
        _finished = NO;
        _expectedSize = 0;
        responseFromCached = YES; // Initially wrong until `connection:willCacheResponse:` is called or not called
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)start {
    @synchronized (self) {
        if (self.isCancelled) {
            self.finished = YES;
            [self reset];
            return;
        }

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_4_0
        Class UIApplicationClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIApplication");
        BOOL hasApplication = UIApplicationClass && [UIApplicationClass respondsToSelector:@selector(sharedApplication)];
        if (hasApplication && [self shouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground]) {
            __weak __typeof__ (self) wself = self;
            UIApplication * app = [UIApplicationClass performSelector:@selector(sharedApplication)];
            self.backgroundTaskId = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
                __strong __typeof (wself) sself = wself;

                if (sself) {
                    [sself cancel];

                    [app endBackgroundTask:sself.backgroundTaskId];
                    sself.backgroundTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
                }
            }];
        }
#endif

        self.executing = YES;
        self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
        self.thread = [NSThread currentThread];
    }

    [self.connection start];

    if (self.connection) {
        if (self.progressBlock) {
            self.progressBlock(0, NSURLResponseUnknownLength);
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SDWebImageDownloadStartNotification object:self];
        });

        if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_5_1) {
            // Make sure to run the runloop in our background thread so it can process downloaded data
            // Note: we use a timeout to work around an issue with NSURLConnection cancel under iOS 5
            //       not waking up the runloop, leading to dead threads (see https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/466)
            CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 10, false);
        }
        else {
            CFRunLoopRun();
        }

        if (!self.isFinished) {
            [self.connection cancel];
            [self connection:self.connection didFailWithError:[NSError errorWithDomain:NSURLErrorDomain code:NSURLErrorTimedOut userInfo:@{NSURLErrorFailingURLErrorKey : self.request.URL}]];
        }
    }
    else {
        if (self.completedBlock) {
            self.completedBlock(nil, nil, [NSError errorWithDomain:NSURLErrorDomain code:0 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : @"Connection can't be initialized"}], YES);
        }
    }

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_4_0
    Class UIApplicationClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIApplication");
    if(!UIApplicationClass || ![UIApplicationClass respondsToSelector:@selector(sharedApplication)]) {
        return;
    }
    if (self.backgroundTaskId != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
        UIApplication * app = [UIApplication performSelector:@selector(sharedApplication)];
        [app endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTaskId];
        self.backgroundTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }
#endif
}

- (void)cancel {
    @synchronized (self) {
        if (self.thread) {
            [self performSelector:@selector(cancelInternalAndStop) onThread:self.thread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
        else {
            [self cancelInternal];
        }
    }
}

- (void)cancelInternalAndStop {
    if (self.isFinished) return;
    [self cancelInternal];
    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}

- (void)cancelInternal {
    if (self.isFinished) return;
    [super cancel];
    if (self.cancelBlock) self.cancelBlock();

    if (self.connection) {
        [self.connection cancel];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SDWebImageDownloadStopNotification object:self];
        });

        // As we cancelled the connection, its callback won't be called and thus won't
        // maintain the isFinished and isExecuting flags.
        if (self.isExecuting) self.executing = NO;
        if (!self.isFinished) self.finished = YES;
    }

    [self reset];
}

- (void)done {
    self.finished = YES;
    self.executing = NO;
    [self reset];
}

- (void)reset {
    self.cancelBlock = nil;
    self.completedBlock = nil;
    self.progressBlock = nil;
    self.connection = nil;
    self.imageData = nil;
    self.thread = nil;
}

- (void)setFinished:(BOOL)finished {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    _finished = finished;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}

- (void)setExecuting:(BOOL)executing {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    _executing = executing;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
}

- (BOOL)isConcurrent {
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark NSURLConnection (delegate)

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    //'304 Not Modified' is an exceptional one
    if (![response respondsToSelector:@selector(statusCode)] || ([((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response) statusCode] < 400 && [((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response) statusCode] != 304)) {
        NSInteger expected = response.expectedContentLength > 0 ? (NSInteger)response.expectedContentLength : 0;
        self.expectedSize = expected;
        if (self.progressBlock) {
            self.progressBlock(0, expected);
        }

        self.imageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:expected];
        self.response = response;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SDWebImageDownloadReceiveResponseNotification object:self];
        });
    }
    else {
        NSUInteger code = [((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response) statusCode];

        //This is the case when server returns '304 Not Modified'. It means that remote image is not changed.
        //In case of 304 we need just cancel the operation and return cached image from the cache.
        if (code == 304) {
            [self cancelInternal];
        } else {
            [self.connection cancel];
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SDWebImageDownloadStopNotification object:self];
        });

        if (self.completedBlock) {
            self.completedBlock(nil, nil, [NSError errorWithDomain:NSURLErrorDomain code:[((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response) statusCode] userInfo:nil], YES);
        }
        CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
        [self done];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.imageData appendData:data];

    if ((self.options & SDWebImageDownloaderProgressiveDownload) && self.expectedSize > 0 && self.completedBlock) {
        // The following code is from http://www.cocoaintheshell.com/2011/05/progressive-images-download-imageio/
        // Thanks to the author @Nyx0uf

        // Get the total bytes downloaded
        const NSInteger totalSize = self.imageData.length;

        // Update the data source, we must pass ALL the data, not just the new bytes
        CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)self.imageData, NULL);

        if (width + height == 0) {
            CFDictionaryRef properties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, NULL);
            if (properties) {
                NSInteger orientationValue = -1;
                CFTypeRef val = CFDictionaryGetValue(properties, kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight);
                if (val) CFNumberGetValue(val, kCFNumberLongType, &height);
                val = CFDictionaryGetValue(properties, kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth);
                if (val) CFNumberGetValue(val, kCFNumberLongType, &width);
                val = CFDictionaryGetValue(properties, kCGImagePropertyOrientation);
                if (val) CFNumberGetValue(val, kCFNumberNSIntegerType, &orientationValue);
                CFRelease(properties);

                // When we draw to Core Graphics, we lose orientation information,
                // which means the image below born of initWithCGIImage will be
                // oriented incorrectly sometimes. (Unlike the image born of initWithData
                // in connectionDidFinishLoading.) So save it here and pass it on later.
                orientation = [[self class] orientationFromPropertyValue:(orientationValue == -1 ? 1 : orientationValue)];
            }

        }

        if (width + height > 0 && totalSize < self.expectedSize) {
            // Create the image
            CGImageRef partialImageRef = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSource, 0, NULL);

#ifdef TARGET_OS_IPHONE
            // Workaround for iOS anamorphic image
            if (partialImageRef) {
                const size_t partialHeight = CGImageGetHeight(partialImageRef);
                CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
                CGContextRef bmContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, width * 4, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
                CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
                if (bmContext) {
                    CGContextDrawImage(bmContext, (CGRect){.origin.x = 0.0f, .origin.y = 0.0f, .size.width = width, .size.height = partialHeight}, partialImageRef);
                    CGImageRelease(partialImageRef);
                    partialImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bmContext);
                    CGContextRelease(bmContext);
                }
                else {
                    CGImageRelease(partialImageRef);
                    partialImageRef = nil;
                }
            }
#endif

            if (partialImageRef) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:partialImageRef scale:1 orientation:orientation];
                NSString *key = [[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] cacheKeyForURL:self.request.URL];
                UIImage *scaledImage = [self scaledImageForKey:key image:image];
                if (self.shouldDecompressImages) {
                    image = [UIImage decodedImageWithImage:scaledImage];
                }
                else {
                    image = scaledImage;
                }
                CGImageRelease(partialImageRef);
                dispatch_main_sync_safe(^{
                    if (self.completedBlock) {
                        self.completedBlock(image, nil, nil, NO);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        CFRelease(imageSource);
    }

    if (self.progressBlock) {
        self.progressBlock(self.imageData.length, self.expectedSize);
    }
}

+ (UIImageOrientation)orientationFromPropertyValue:(NSInteger)value {
    switch (value) {
        case 1:
            return UIImageOrientationUp;
        case 3:
            return UIImageOrientationDown;
        case 8:
            return UIImageOrientationLeft;
        case 6:
            return UIImageOrientationRight;
        case 2:
            return UIImageOrientationUpMirrored;
        case 4:
            return UIImageOrientationDownMirrored;
        case 5:
            return UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored;
        case 7:
            return UIImageOrientationRightMirrored;
        default:
            return UIImageOrientationUp;
    }
}

- (UIImage *)scaledImageForKey:(NSString *)key image:(UIImage *)image {
    return SDScaledImageForKey(key, image);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection {
    SDWebImageDownloaderCompletedBlock completionBlock = self.completedBlock;
    @synchronized(self) {
        CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
        self.thread = nil;
        self.connection = nil;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SDWebImageDownloadStopNotification object:self];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SDWebImageDownloadFinishNotification object:self];
        });
    }

    if (![[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:_request]) {
        responseFromCached = NO;
    }

    if (completionBlock) {
        if (self.options & SDWebImageDownloaderIgnoreCachedResponse && responseFromCached) {
            completionBlock(nil, nil, nil, YES);
        } else if (self.imageData) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage sd_imageWithData:self.imageData];
            NSString *key = [[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] cacheKeyForURL:self.request.URL];
            image = [self scaledImageForKey:key image:image];

            // Do not force decoding animated GIFs
            if (!image.images) {
                if (self.shouldDecompressImages) {
                    image = [UIImage decodedImageWithImage:image];
                }
            }
            if (CGSizeEqualToSize(image.size, CGSizeZero)) {
                completionBlock(nil, nil, [NSError errorWithDomain:SDWebImageErrorDomain code:0 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : @"Downloaded image has 0 pixels"}], YES);
            }
            else {
                completionBlock(image, self.imageData, nil, YES);
            }
        } else {
            completionBlock(nil, nil, [NSError errorWithDomain:SDWebImageErrorDomain code:0 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : @"Image data is nil"}], YES);
        }
    }
    self.completionBlock = nil;
    [self done];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    @synchronized(self) {
        CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
        self.thread = nil;
        self.connection = nil;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SDWebImageDownloadStopNotification object:self];
        });
    }

    if (self.completedBlock) {
        self.completedBlock(nil, nil, error, YES);
    }
    self.completionBlock = nil;
    [self done];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse {
    responseFromCached = NO; // If this method is called, it means the response wasn't read from cache
    if (self.request.cachePolicy == NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData) {
        // Prevents caching of responses
        return nil;
    }
    else {
        return cachedResponse;
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground {
    return self.options & SDWebImageDownloaderContinueInBackground;
}

- (BOOL)connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage:(NSURLConnection __unused *)connection {
    return self.shouldUseCredentialStorage;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        if (!(self.options & SDWebImageDownloaderAllowInvalidSSLCertificates) &&
            [challenge.sender respondsToSelector:@selector(performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:)]) {
            [challenge.sender performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        } else {
            NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
            [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
    } else {
        if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
            if (self.credential) {
                [[challenge sender] useCredential:self.credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
            } else {
                [[challenge sender] continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
            }
        } else {
            [[challenge sender] continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

The line with the error is,

```
CFRunLoopRun();
```